# Using EmbeddedValueResolver with @Conditional

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Problem context: in our application we use custom `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` to extend possibilities of `EmbeddedValueResolver` with custom property sources. I am very inspired of Spring Boot `@ConditionalOnProperty` and `@ConditionalOnExpression` and want to use it with custom placeholders.

What I wanted to do was to write custom `@Conditional` annotation that uses `EmbeddedValueResolver` to resolve placeholders (`${...}`). I noticed that `ConfigurationClassPostProcessor` implements `ResourceLoaderAware` interface, and `ResourceLoaderAware` classes are configured later than `EmbeddedValueResolverAware` ones. So when we initialize `ResourceLoaderAware`, our `EmbeddedValueResolverAware` beans are already configured. So potentially solution seems possible.

What I wanted to do next was to write custom `Condition` that uses `EmbeddedValueResolver` from `ApplicationContext` to resolve some property and match it to some value. But the problem is that `Condition` uses some another context class called `ConditionContext` which doesn't include `EmbeddedValueResolver`. Using `Environment#resolvePlaceholder` doesn't help - seems like `Environment` doesn't know anything about placeholders that are available through `EmbeddedValueResolver`.

So, is that possible to use `EmbeddedValueResolver` with Spring conditionals?

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example of what you are looking to be able to do?

Comment: I'd like to be able to use placeholders (which are available through `@Value` annotation, like `@Value("${auth.enabled}")`)  with Conditionals, like `@ConditionalOnValue("${auth.enabled}", "true")`.